# MSIL of System.Int32 and int will be same?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, int or Int32? Should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care)

Please any one let me know MSIL of System.Int32 and int will be same or different, If different then which one we should use.

**Edit:**

this won't compile

```
public  enum MyEnum : Int32
{
    AEnum = 0
}
```

but this will

```
public enum MyEnum : int
{
    AEnum = 0
}
```

Comment: It is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care

Comment: For more details check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005319/why-cant-i-declare-an-enum-inheriting-from-byte-but-i-can-from-byte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int` is an alias for `System.Int32`, they are completely the same.

`enums` only take integral types as type, as this would be possible otherwise:

```
using Int32 = System.String;

public enum Something : Int32
{
}
```

This is according to C# spec, which states

```
enum-declaration:
[attributes] [enum-modifiers ] enum identifier [enum-base] enum-body [;]

where
enum-base:
":" integral-type
```

With integral type specified as:

```
integral-type:
sbyte
byte
short
ushort
int
uint
long
ulong
char
```

Comment: I have edited my question, Please check now

Comment: @Pankaj: Your edit shows one small corner-case where `int` and `Int32` aren't interchangeable, and in that situation the compiler tells you about it. You can safely assume that whenever the compiler doesn't produce any errors then the resulting IL will be exactly the same for `int` or `Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w(v=VS.100).aspx

Type: int
.NET Framework type: System.Int32

Comment: I have edited my question, Please check now

Answer (score 1):

Both are same but `int` is  [language specification is the definitive source for C# syntax and usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx)

> **Int32** is an immutable value type that represents signed integers with
>   values that range from negative
>   2,147,483,648 (which is represented by
>   the Int32.MinValue constant) through
>   positive 2,147,483,647 (which is
>   represented by the Int32.MaxValue
>   constant.
>   From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`int` is an alias for `System.Int32` so there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

These are Exactly same as everyone already told `int` is an alias for `Int32`.

You can experiment it yourself place a mouse over `int` in visual studio and Click **"Go to Decleration"**.
Same as `int` `string` is also an alias for `String`

Answer (score 0):

Confirm. System.Int32 doesn't work. Mono 2.8 compiler sais:

```
t.cs(3,29): error CS1008: Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, 
uint, long or ulong expected
```

So it appears to be a hardcoded language definition rule.

---

<sup>Trying to be devil's advocate here:</sup>

Perhaps you are running into a name clash, and you have Int32 defined elsewhere (I haven't tried whether that is legal, but it might be a problem). Try qualifying it:

```
 public  enum MyEnum : System.Int32
 {
    AEnum = 0
 }
```

Comment: System.Int32 also not working, Can you please check once?