# Use of 'Common Type System' as coding standard

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style, clr

One of our coding standard 'rules' is:

> - Use the common type system. For example, use `Int32` instead of `int`.

I have not seen a similar rule before, although our other guidelines are roughly based on Microsoft's [Design Guidelines Digest](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/09/28/235232.aspx). It doesn't seem like what the [Common Type System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Type_System) is, either.

I find it inconvenient as I end up having to rewrite default Visual Studio and ReSharper refactorings to convert `string` to `String`, `float` to `Single`, `long` to `Int64` etc.
It's also applied fairly inconsistently (e.g. not for `object` to `Object`), possibly as a consequence of its inconvenience, and no StyleCop rule exists to check it is applied.

I am therefore wondering why this rule was ever set. Could there be a good reason? Are there any cases (perhaps historical) where `Int32` must be used instead of `int` for example?

**Update**:

I read through the recommended Framework Design Guidelines (2006, Cwalina & Adams) section 3.2.3 *Avoiding Language-Specific Names* and they state "*it is important to avoid the use of these language-specific type names **in identifiers***" (my emphasis). Agreed.

However, Jeffrey Richter then goes on to comment "*I take this a step farther and never use the language's alias names [as it] adds nothing of value and introduces enormous confusion*".
Perhaps this is where this rule has come from?

Comment: maybe someone with a c/c++ portability background got paranoid?

Comment: and there few cases where you can't use the common type system. One example: did you ever [try to inherit an enum from System.Int16 instead of byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005319/why-cant-i-declare-an-enum-inheriting-from-byte-but-i-can-from-byte) ?

Comment: If that's the exact wording, whoever wrote it was confused. In C#, `int` is an **exact synonym** for `System.Int32` and therefore is just as much part of the 'common type system'. Now, if they'd written "use type's native names rather than the C# synonyms", they would at least have been being accurate (though still misguided, IMO)

Comment: If the rule is inconvenient then change it. In fact I wrote the opposite in our coding standards :)

Comment: Our coding standards say to use the alias type names for variables, e.g. `string` and `int` and use the C# synonyms for static member access, e.g. `Int32.MaxValue` and `String.Format`. We find this makes it clearer as it adheres more to naming standards (i.e. class and struct names should be Pascal Case). Lowercase is used for `string` and `int` and other variables that can be declared `const`; `Object` is used instead of `object` because it cannot be declared `const`.

Comment: I like using the actual types if I want to emphasize the bit size. But I see no reason to use them everywhere.

Comment: @SteveB Yes, I have been in that exact situation! It's even partly why I asked the question. At least I can take solace in Jon Skeet's pity...

Comment: @Lukazoid That sounds like a much better system, albeit slightly more complicated at first glance. Didn't consider Object/object - interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this rule comes from a misinterpretation of the framework guidelines.

The guidelines say in the [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) section:

> **Do use a generic common language runtime (CLR) type name, rather than a language-specific name, in the rare cases when an identifier has no semantic meaning beyond its type.**
>
> For example, a method that converts data to `Int16` should be named `ToInt16`, not `ToShort` because `Short` is the language-specific type name for `Int16`.

If you create identifiers which contain a type as part of their name, for example a set of `SomeType ReadSomeType()` methods, then you should use the actual type name for `SomeType` and not the C# alias.

A programmer who works in a different language might associate different meanings with a type. For example if you had a `ReadFloat()` method, a C# programmer would assume it returns `System.Single`, and a F# programmer would assume it returns `System.Double`. So you should name it `ReadSingle` or `ReadDouble`.

This rule does not apply to the simple type names you use to refer to a type in your code. A programmer consuming your library will never see which for you used.

Comment: Personally I use the type-name and not the keywords because it isn't very consistent to use the keywords IMO. All the types have a certain highlight, start with a capital letter, and then suddenly the keywords arrive. Take this for example: `void MyFunction(MyClass mc, DateTime time, int num, MyDerClass mdc)`. The `int` just doesn't fit there, especially with the syntax highlighting. I much prefer `Int32`, even tho I had to get used to it (kinda weird, especially if you're coming from another programming language where `int` is the only option). So I'm not so sure it's a misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2):

There's a recommendation for [*Class Library Developers*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx), in reference to the *exposed* names:

> Do use a generic common language runtime (CLR) type name, rather than a language-specific name, in the rare cases when an identifier has no semantic meaning beyond its type.

However, it has never, to me knowledge, been a recommendation when it comes to e.g. internal variables.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reson for this, but I must caveat this by saying I have only used version 3.5+ of the framework and there maybe some historical reason I am not aware of. Basically the simple types (`int`) are just aliases for predefined `struct` types (`System.Int32`). Some points that might help you establish that the reaons for doing this are unneccessary, come directly from the C# laungage guide...

"*Simple Types* are identified through reserved words (`sbyte`, `byte`, ... , `int`, `long`, ... , `float`, `double`), but these reserved words are simply aliases for predefined `struct` types in the `System` namespace (`System.SByte`, `System.Byte`, ... , `System.Int32`, etc.). Because a simple type aliases a `struct` type, every simple type has members. For example `int` has the members declared in `System.Int32` and the members inherited from `System.Object` and statements like

```
int i = int.MaxValue;    // System.int32.MaxValue constant.
string s = i.ToString(); // System.Int32.ToString() instance method.
```

are permitted."

This goes on, buut the general jist is that the simple types are merely aliases - that's it. There is no reason for doing what you describe what-so-ever.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This rule makes sense if you work in a multi-language environment or if you are developing  a framework or a shared library.

Firts, it guarantees that all used types are supported by CLS (see [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx)). Second, it avoids possible confusion caused by the same type having different names in different .Net languages.

This topic is discussed in the book "Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .Net Libraries", which I strongly recommend.

[Common Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx)

Comment: "Firsts, it guarantees that all used types are supported by CLR." what do you mean by that?

Comment: Chapter 3.2.3 [Avoiding Language-Specific Names](http://books.google.it/books?id=39d1wZ598ecC&lpg=PT32&pg=PT97#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @CodeInChaos I mean CLS. Added a relevant reference to the answer.

Comment: While using CLS compliant types has certain advantages, I don't see how using the actual type-names guarantees that types are CLS compliant any more than using aliases. I can write `UInt32` just as easily as I can write `uint`. To ensure CLS compliance, use the attributes designed for that. This is orthogonal to the coding style choice of keyword aliases vs. typenames.

Comment: I can see why external naming is important, and have even changed some function names based on FxCop recommendations (ReadFloat() to ReadSingle() for example). But the type of local variables are internal and therefore not directly related to CLS naming standards. But interesting links, thanks.

Comment: Also noticed that the Framework Design Guidelines book you mention has the same author as the Guidelines digest link in my question - Krzysztof Cwalina. Perhaps he explicitly recommends this coding style somewhere?

Comment: @CodeInChaos Agree. it's, well, a bit off topic.